# When label dimension is less then number of last layer

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

If I have one label, one value to predict at each time, but If I write the following way the last layer `tf.Keras.layers.Dense(3)`, the number of prediction value is 3, but I don't understand what is the rest 2 value, where they come from. I expected that this code gives me an error because the label dimension is less than the number of the last layers. Note:It is an LSTM model, with the last dense layer.
Additionally, if the label dimension equals the number of the last layer, does it means it fits one-by-one? I mean is it multi-task learning?
For example: If I have label (1,2,3) and `model.predict(data)=(1,2,3)`, is the output of 1 prediction of real values "1" and so on and so for

Comment: In this case the label will be broadcasted to match the last dense layer output dimensions. And no, it won't be a one-by-one thing, as the outputs of your last dense layer all are calculated at once

Comment: Thank you, Can you tell me what you mean at once?

Comment: I mean, all the three output values(of last dense layer) are a result of one matrix multiplication, so they happen simultaneously(at once)